# Should I be compensated for an hour's worth of work when I am working only 15 minutes?

Tags: new-job, negotiation

I work in home healthcare, traveling to various client homes to provide care. To get to work, it is a 15 minute drive each way. Sometimes I am asked to stop in on a client for just 15 minutes. That means that with travel time, it is a 45 minute trip. I am not paid mileage or gas, and they want to compensate me for just 15 minutes. This comes out to roughly $2.75 for 45 minutes of my time. As an employee, is it reasonable for me to expect to be compensated for an hour's worth of time? I'm not sure how to handle this situation because it's a new job, and I did not realize this was how the pay works.

So to sum it up, it is reasonable to expect an hour's pay for 15 minutes of actual hands-on work, plus 30 minutes of driving?

Comment: (http://www.dol.gov/whd/regs/compliance/whdfs22.htm) says "Time spent by an employee in travel as part of their principal activity, such as travel from job site to job site during the workday, is work time and must be counted as hours worked.". That is distinct from travel from and to home at the start and end of the work day. What country are you in?

Comment: Even if you expect them to cover travel how do you come up with 1 hour

Comment: In the US, they must pay you for time spent on-call that your company is in control of. Situation A, you're at home doing what you will while waiting for an infrequent call, you have control of this time: they do not need to pay you. Situation B, you're driving around on behalf of your company, thus your company is in control of this time, they must pay you.

Comment: Depends on local law, but often times the company is legally required to pay for all travel other than the commute. They often have to reimburse you for travel costs too. Traveling to a 15 minute assignment at a client's location is not commuting. In some cases rates for travel and work may be different.

Comment: Who are you negotiating with to decide what you are getting paid for?  Does the client pay the company, who pays you?  Or is this like a contracting or franchising firm where the company is only facilitating your jobs for the clients?  It sounds like you need to set a "minimum charge" for each call.  If this is not an option (company controls costing) you need to create a concrete set of documentation showing exactly how much time you are spending (maybe do a 2 week example) and exactly how much you were paid.  Who gets to make the decision about how much you are paid?  Present it to them.

Comment: Then, once you have your documentation showing how much you are making per hour, ask your employer if they consider this a fair wage.  If they say yes, and you disagree, I'm sorry but your only recourse is to vote with your feet.  It doesn't matter what kind of advice we give you if you don't have any control over your options.

Answer (score 5):

Your situation is why repair companies have a steep base charge just to look at the item. They realize that they spend time driving between each work site, and may end up frequently in situations where the time spent diagnosing, and repairing the time is a small part of the whole day.

If they are only compensating you for the time you have contact with the patient, you may have to rethink your work situation. Of course their ability to bill adequately to cover the travel time may be limited by their contracts.

You should look into the requirements for documenting your mileage/gas because depending on your country you may be able to deduct those expenses.

Answer (score 1):

> reasonable to expect an hour's pay for 15 minutes of actual hands-on work, plus 30 minutes of driving?

Yes it is reasonable. It depends on the company, but all businesses I know of factor in the time spent travelling as part of their charges.

I do a lot of work at two widely seperated airports, fixing a problem at one of them might cost me half a day in terms of time, for a job that might take ten minutes. I charge the half day. For other clients I have a set call out rate for the sole purpose of covering travel time and expenses regardless of how long the actual job takes. When I'm required to travel to another Island or the neighbouring country I negotiate a cost that takes it into account.

Answer (score -1):

> So to sum it up, it is reasonable to expect an hour's pay for 15
>   minutes of actual hands-on work, plus 30 minutes of driving?

Yes, in your case it is reasonable to expect to be compensated for the driving time. You are not "commuting to a site" you are driving to various locations as a requirement of the job. That does not mean you will get compensation, but it is not unreasonable. You have a few options that may help.

"Commuting" is probably not what you are being asked to do. You may want to ask the Dept of Labor (http://www.dol.gov/whd/regs/compliance/whdfs22.htm) because the time you are driving (or even waiting to be assigned a client) may be considered "work" for which you are not being compensated. This is more of a legal route, so it may not be the best, but it might help you feel better and/or know your rights better.

If you discuss this with your employer to simply try to resolve it without the legal approach, it might be that hourly rates apply, but likely mileage will work. Your employer will then have a fixed cost compared to traffic problems. However, most days without traffic you will benefit from the arrangement.

If this doesn't work and you continue the job, you should look into "unreimbursed employee expenses" - it might help with your tax situation (it might not, I'm not a lawyer or CPA).